# How button get focus on click in android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout xml file i created a screen with three button with the background,
now when user clicks on it. It doesn't show any sign that is is clicked 
How can I achieve this any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you set a onClickListener?

Comment: I think you should google before posting a question. This has been answered in a lot of different places.

Comment: Hello Hades I have searched it for many times but I don't get any satisfactory answer. Actually my question is somewhat different. I have a button with an background image. so when i click on it, It doesn't show any focus or any color change on it. Hope you getting my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.

To indicate the different button states (focused, selected, etc.), you can define a different image for each state

Save the XML file in your project res/drawable/ folder and then reference it as a drawable for the source of your ImageButton (in the android:src attribute). Android will automatically change the image based on the state of the button and the corresponding images defined in the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
   <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure but, we need to set hover by xml

```
<item
        android:color="hex_color"
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I manage to find the answer by myself.
what I have done

```
    final Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmaphome);
    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lodclick);
            // rest of the code
        }
    });
```

here I have another image and I set it as background when button got clicked another image set as background on button and it seems like button got focused.
Thanx to all.

Answer (score 0):

make these three xml file in drawable folder.
custom_background_focus.xml

{

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#111111" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#fcfcfc"
        android:startColor="#fcfcfc" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

custom_background_normal.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#333333" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="225"
            android:endColor="#999999"
            android:startColor="#999999" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
            android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

    </shape>
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/custom_background_focus" /> <!-- pressed -->
   <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/custom_background_focus" /> <!-- focused -->
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_background_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```